# Oracle Trigger to kill session

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

Is it possible to create a trigger to look for sql text have the keyword "CONTAINS" and kill the sql session?

Comment: if `contains` is data - yes. If DDL - no. Then, anyways, how you're going to kill session in the trigger? You can stop the action, throw an error, etc

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to fire a trigger on every SQL statement.  Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?  For example, if CONTAINS queries are running too slowly, you could create a scheduler job that runs every minutes, checks everything in GV$SQL for CONTAINS, and kills sessions running those statements.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i2013